# Postfix Expressions advantages?

Tags: postfix-notation, polish-notation

What are advantages of post-fix expressions over prefix expressions? What can be the disadvantages of prefix expressions that can be removed using postfix expressions?

Answer (score 0):

You can [see here](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/cs212/fix.html)

> Postfix and Prefix notations have similar complexity, Postfix is slightly easier to evaluate in simple circumstances as the operators really are evaluated strictly left-to-right.

Fore more about Infix, Prefix and Postfix Expressions you can [read](http://ice-web.cc.gatech.edu/ce21/1/static/CSPrinciples/_static/audio/static/pythonds/BasicDS/InfixPrefixandPostfixExpressions.html) this.